# Is it possible to call RichTextValueBuilder.setTextStyle( ) multiple times programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got this these values.

[image]

And I want to have this result.

[image]

So I made the following test code and tried it to the first cell.

```js
function test2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("richText3");
  const range1 = sheet.getRange("A1");
  const text1 = range1.getValue();
  Logger.log(text1);
  const re = new RegExp(/\([ a-zA-Z\/']*\)\?/dg);  
  const redBold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('red').build();
  let array;
  while ((array = re.exec(text1)) !== null) {
    const [start, end] = array.indices[0];
    const richTxtValBlder = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(text1)
        .setTextStyle(start, end, redBold)
        .build();
    range1.setRichTextValue(richTxtValBlder);   
  }  
}
```

After first try, I got this result.

[image]

I checked the [Reference Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#settextstylestartoffset,-endoffset,-textstyle) again and I found this comment.

> **setText(text)** : Sets the text for this value and ***clears any existing text style.***
> When creating a new Rich Text value, ***this should be called before setTextStyle()***

I found that I should call `.setText()` once and call `.setTextStyle()` multiple times.
But the problem is `.setTextStyle()` should be called programmatically according to the number of patterns in each cell and I cannot find how to do it programmatically.

Each cell may have 0 to 10 patterns and I don't want to make 10 different `richTExtValueBuilder` which only differ in the number of `.setTextStyle()` calls.

Do you have any different ideas ?

Comment: Try it yourself and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, only cell "A1" is used, and also the 1st match is used. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue.
- In order to achieve your goal, I retrieve the values from column "A". And also, I use `matchAll` instead of `exec`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function test2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("richText3");
  const range1 = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const re = new RegExp(/\([ a-zA-Z\/']*\)\?/g);
  const redBold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('red').build();
  const richTextValues = range1.getRichTextValues();
  const res = richTextValues.map(([a]) => {
    const array = [...a.getText().matchAll(re)];
    if (array) {
      const temp = a.copy();
      array.forEach(a => temp.setTextStyle(a.index, a.index + a[0].length, redBold));
      return [temp.build()];
    }
    return [a];
  });
  range1.setRichTextValues(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to call `.setText()` once, `.setTextStyle()` multiple times, and `.build()` once, e.g. change your `while` loop. Untested code:

```
    let richTxtValBlder = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text1);
    while ((array = re.exec(text1)) !== null) {
        const [start, end] = array.indices[0];
        richTxtValBlder = richTxtValBlder.setTextStyle(start, end, redBold);
    }
    richTxtValBlder = richTxtValBlder.build();
    range1.setRichTextValue(richTxtValBlder);
```

Comment: I tested your code and it give me this `Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.RichTextValueBuilder) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setRichTextValue.` . So I changed the last part of your code like this `const richText = richTxtValBlder.build(); range1.setRichTextValue(richText);` .  Your answer is very close to my original idea but I found another answer is more helpful. So I didn't accept your answer.